# Rigid Body objects passing through container

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I am tiring to simulate a tic tac box shacking and moving from side to side.
I tried to play with the collision margins but still noting change, in some speed the objects just fly through the box.

Cheers and thanks for all the helpers

[image]

Comment: Could you upload blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. It could be due to wall thickness of container or object scale or something different. It's hard to tell.

Comment: Make sure u don’t have deactivation on for the pills inside and make sure the block is in passive and the pills are in active